# Log-linearization of an intertemporal budget constraint

Tags: macroeconomics

I'm trying to recreate the paper "Learning about Monetary Policy Rules when
Long-Horizon Expectations Matter" by Preston.

At one point he says that he log linearizes the intertemporal budget constraint

$$W_{t}^{i}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} R_{t, t+j}\left[P_{t+j} C_{t+j}^{i}-P_{t+j} Y_{t+j}^{i}\right]$$

where $W_{t}^{i} \equiv\left(1+i_{t-1}\right) B_{t-1}$, $\bar{\imath}_{t}=\beta^{-1}-1$ (denoting the steady state of $i$), $\hat{i}=\log [(1+i) /(1+\bar{i})]= log \frac{R_{t,t+1}}{R}$  in order to obtain
$$\hat{E}_{t}^{i} \sum_{T=t}^{\infty} \beta^{T-t} \hat{C}_{T}^{i}=\varpi_{t}^{i}+\hat{E}_{t}^{i} \sum_{T=t}^{\infty} \beta^{T-t} \hat{Y}_{T}^{i}$$

with $\varpi_{t}^{i} \equiv W_{t}^{i} /\left(P_{t} \bar{Y}\right)$.

I tried a houndred times to linearize the budget constraint but i can't really figure out what he did.

Since $ln x_t = ln x -  \hat x_t \rightarrow x_t = x  e^{\hat x_t}$ i wrote the the intertemporal budget constraint as

\begin{align} 
W_t^i =&\sum_j^{\infty} R e^{\hat R_{t,t+1}} P e^{\hat P_{t+j}} \left[ ( C e^{\hat C_t+j}) - (Y e^{\hat Y_t})\right]\\
W_t^i=& \sum_j^{\infty} RP e^{\hat R_{t,t+1} + \hat P_{t+j}} \left[ ( C e^{\hat C_t+j}) - (Y e^{\hat Y_t})\right] \\
W_t^i \approx & \sum_j^{\infty} RP (1+ \hat R_{t,t+1}+ \hat P_{t+j}) \left[  (C(1+\hat C_{t+j})(Y(1+ \hat Y_{t+j})\right]
\end{align}
ANd then i don't know how to procede. Where do the steady state values of $R$ and $C$ disappear?

Comment: You should show us at least one of the attempts at log linearization you did per rules of this forum to show us some effort.

Comment: I added one but i think it's completely wrong

Comment: that’s completely fine at least you show us you tried

Comment: Haven't looked at the detailed calculations yet. But have you replaced the steady state values and conditions in your log linearized equation? If you havent done it, that could be a potential source of error.

Comment: Which steady state value do you suggest? My problem is that W_t^i (LHS on the first equation) also appears in the log linearized one  in the term ϖ_t^i. @Tomcat